# In dark matches, do I "see" killed enemies that are out of my line of sight?

Tags: frozen-synapse

Imagine for a moment that - in a dark match - I fire a rocket, which then successfully kills an enemy unit, but does so completely outside the line of sight for any of my units.

Am I informed of this kill?
Do I see that unit as dead, or "last seen at ..."?
Can I spot the body later to have the unit classified as down from then on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Even in darkness, you see all projectiles and deaths.